# Is there a way to run one defined and X number of random TestNG tests from different packages (or classes)?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to help my teammates to write more stable and isolated Selenium UI Automation tests using TestNG. 
So I am wondering if someone have experience implementing something like below:

1. Randomly select 6 tests from Functional and\or Smoke test package
2. Put newly developed test in the middle of the suite
3. Run above configuration 3 times changing random test selection in the pack before each run

Answer (score 0):

By default, TestNG is designed to run tests according to priority and order.

If you wish to run tests randomly you must write a method that will select some of your test methods, and push them into your test suite XML file.

Something like this:

```
 private void addRandomTests()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<String> testsCode = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int n = rnd.nextInt(10);
        // if your test methods are called Test1, Test2, Test3 etc'
        // Otherwise change this code
        testsCode.add("Test"+n);
    }
    // Manipulate the XML test suite by adding more test tags
    AddTestToSuites(testsCode);
}
```